# Javascript replace middle of string between two characters

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to replace a string like below:

```
Firstname Lastname : domain\999999
```

into:

```
Firstname Lastname : 999999
```

How would I do this using Javascript? I'm assuming a replace between the : character and \ character.

Thanks

Comment: something like this: txtValue.replace(/:.*\//, ': ');

Comment: You need ``\\`` not ``\/``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var str = 'Firstname Lastname : domain\\999999';

console.log(
  str.replace(/(:\s*)[^\\]+\\/, '$1')
)
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/bR6wN6/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]